# Not getting Formdata in post using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to get formdata to my php file. but i'm getting not any value on post. please advice me what i'm doing is right? i'm doing something wrong in post

```
// add item to additem
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#additembutton").click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($("form #itemform")[0]);
    alert(formData);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'additem.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
        return false;
});
    </script>

// form submit image
```

This is my additem.php file

```
<?php
include '../class/dbconfig.php';
$filename=$_POST['myfile']['name'];
echo $_POST['myfile'];
```

This is my html form

```
 <form class="form-horizontal"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="select" class="col-md-3 control-label">Menu Type</label>
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <select class="form-control" id="menutype">
 <option>Select Menu</option>
 <option value="fastfood">FastFood</option>
 <option value="other">Other</option>
 </select>
 </div>
 </div>
 <!--
 <div class="form-group" id="otherdiv">
 <label for="menuorder" class="col-md-3 control-label">Other Menu Type</label>
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <input type="number" class="form-control" id="othermenu"  placeholder="Enter Order">
 </div>
 </div>
 -->
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="menuorder" class="col-md-3 control-label">Menu Order</label>
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <input type="number" class="form-control" id="menuorder" pattern="[0-9]+" placeholder="Enter Order">
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="select" class="col-md-3 control-label">Menu Status</label>
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <select class="form-control" id="menustatus">
 <option value="1">Active</option>
 <option value="0">Deactive</option>
 </select>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
 <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addmenubutton" >Submit</button>
 </div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Hmmm it looks like the jQuery selector isn't picking up your form as it has no id="itemForm" attribute but I can test right now to be certain...

Comment: @NeilHibbert is right, your jquery selector is wrong ;)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to send the form via post:

```
<form method="POST">
```

Comment: it was not working, but now it is working. oops. i'm not sure what was the issue

Comment: this is not an answer, the form was sent via POST with the `$.ajax` method. Dont mark as accepted answer what are not, pls.